Path Animation of a collection containing bone animations (steam locomotive with movable wheels and rods)
How can I achieve that a steam locomotive with a) rigid parts such as boiler, chimney etc., b) rotating wheels and c) movable rods which are animated depending on the rotation of the wheels and parented to bones will follow a path?
I understand that I can select all objects in the collection "locomotive" (by the way: only as long as they are visible...!) and parent them to e.g. an empty, which then can get a Follow Path constraint and will "tow" the parented loco parts, but when I do this, the movement of the rods is gone (they stand still and just move together with the whole loco, while the movement of the bones continues). I guess that this is probably due to double parenting, since the rods are at first parented to their bones and now parented to the empty. Is there a standard method to overcome this issue?

There isn't such a thing like double parenting, the rods you're speaking of are now just parented to the empty. Leave anything that's parented to the  armature as is and just parent the armature to the empty. If that doesn't help, it maybe helpful to see some pictures or even better your blend file.
